# UserManager ResetPasswordAsync Exception "key value is already being tracked"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to reset the password on a user using the `ResetPasswordAsync` method on a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`.

```
// Inject the UserManager
[Inject] public UserManager<ApplicationManager> UserManager { get; set; }

// Inject the factory
[Inject] public IDbContextFactory<DataContext> Factory { get; set; }

...

// Reset the password
async Task ResetPasswordAsync (ApplicationUser user)
{
    ...
    
    var context = Factory.CreateDbContext();

    var password = CreatePassword();
    var token = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
    
    // Tried setting the state to detached, but it didn't work
    dataContext.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Detached;

    // This line throws the exception
    await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, password );

}
```

However, that last line throws this exception.

**The instance of entity type 'ApplicationUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.**

I am using entity framework core for the data context, and blazor for the ui.

Comment: Are you shore error line is not Toke generated line? in the last i get the same error when i use `user` class that not find by `UserManager` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, avoid passing detached entities around, it leads to many problems like this.

When you have code like this:

```
var token = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
```

You are passing the detached "user" reference that was passed into the method. Instead, simplify. What would you have done if your method only had the User ID?

```
async Task ResetPasswordAsync (int userId)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    if (user == null) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(userId), "User was not found.");

    var password = CreatePassword();
    var token = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

    await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, password );
}
```

This code would likely work as expected. As a work-around with passing a user reference in:

```
async Task ResetPasswordAsync (ApplicationUser currentUser)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(currentUser.UserId);
    if (user == null) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(currentUser), "User was not found.");

    var password = CreatePassword();
    var token = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

    await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, password );
}
```

Essentially use the User instance reference that the `UserManager` and it's underlying `DbContext` instance will be familiar with, not a detached reference.

The problem with passing a detached user into the method is that while you can pass that detached reference to a method like `GeneratePasswordResetToken`, the `UserManager` is likely going to go and create a Token instance with that User reference. Somewhere that `UserManager`'s `DbContext` may have loaded and is still tracking a reference to the user, so when you go to save the user/token using that detached reference, you can end up getting an error that the underlying `DbContext` is tracking a reference.

In short, to avoid issues like this, design to avoid ever passing entities around beyond the scope of the `DbContext` that read them. This can be tricky with Blazor and WPF applications since that boundary isn't as clearly defined when using injected `DbContext` instances.  If you do have a reason to use detached entities then you have to be careful to check if they are being tracked by the underlying `DbContex`t, and if so replace those references. The solution there is *not* a `DbContextFactory` as that most certainly returns a new `DbContext` instance, you want the `DbContext` reference that in this case `UserManager` would be configured to be using. (What was injected into `UserManager`) So in this case a quicker fix is to just fetch the user reference from `UserManager`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Using the user reference found by the user manager fixed the issue.